# Send message via mobile phone to web server

Tags: iphone, ios4

I try to send title and message to web server. I want to receive response if the request is successful or failure. But I don't from where to start. Can someone help me?

Best regards

Comment: HTTP or another protocol? Foundation namely has classes for HTTP connections and transfers for you.

Comment: I want to use HTTP protocol, but I don't know how to send message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much prefered to use a ASIHTTPRequest for proper error handling, but a quick and dirty solution could be:

```
NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxx.yyy"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
BOOL success = response!=nil && ([response rangeOfString:@"success"].location != NSNotFound);
```

Answer (score 1):

An good library is [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

You can look at apples [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use  [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) it is a wrapper for CFNetowork that lets you easily do what you want.